# Excel when connected to external data: "We found a problеm with some content in [file]"

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013

I have created a spreadsheet in Excel 2013 that gets data from a CSV file, then made a pivot table based on the raw data and a chart to visualise it. The connection was also added to the data model and was configured to refresh upon opening the spredsheet.

However, whenever I open the file I get the error message:

> We found a problem with some content in *[file]*. Do you want us to try
>   to recover as much as we can? If you trust the source of this
>   workbook, click Yes.

[image: We found a problem with some content in "file"]

After I click "Yes", Excel tells me it "was able to open the file by repairing or removing the unreadable content".

[image: Repaired records]

The data seems to update fine. When I save the file again, Excel goes through the "Save as" routine, but lets me overwrite the file anyway.

This process is repeated every damn time I open the file.

- If I unlink the raw data table from the CSV file, the problem disappears.
- If I reconnect to the CSV file, it problem re-appears.
- Even if I remove all other sheets, or start from a new file, and add the CSV file, the problem re-appears.

Comment: Sorry for the l33t-speak, but "problem" is not allowed word in title?!

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/107989/why-cant-we-use-the-word-problem-in-titles

Comment: Couldn't you just edit your question after having posted it?

Comment: Apparently I could, but I had no idea. Assumed same restriction applied.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After much Googling, trial and error I finally stumbled across [this thread](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2013_release-excel/issue-with-csv-import-in-excel-2013-connection/74e47d1c-b227-4e8f-b4fe-958c14a2abaf) on Microsoft Answers, where Sridhar suggests this workaround (emphasis mine):

> This happens only if I "Add to data model" AND set the "Refresh data
>   when opening the file" **during the creation** of the connection.
>
> If I dont set the "Refresh data when opening the file" and create the
>   table and later go to "Connections -> Properties" and it set it again
>   then this does not happen.

I can confirm that this solved the issue in my case too.

This is the checkbox to leave unchecked when adding the connection:

[image: Connection Properties: Refresh data when opening the file]

To enable this option *after* creating the connection:

1. Click on the "Data" tab, then "Connections"

[image: Data/Connections]

3. Select the appropriate connection (not the data model), click "Properties"
4. Check "Refresh data when opening the file" (see screenshot above)
5. Click "OK", then "Close"

Answer (score 1):

As an update on the last answer so that you retain your connections:

1. Open file with 7-zip (no unpacking!)
2. Open folder 'xl'
3. Edit connections.xml
4. Change refreshOnLoad="1" to refreshOnLoad="0"
5. Close and save, update in the archive.
6. Close 7-zip

The file should now open without errors.  You can turn on the refresh on load and seems to work fine.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue on my Mac with Excel 2011. Don't know what happened to face this issue. But anyway, I solved it this way:

1. Open file with 7-zip (no unpacking!)
2. Open folder 'xl' and delete file connections.xml (everything done in 7-zip app)
3. Close 7-zip

Now, my file could be opened without any error. Of course, I kicked all ext connections, but his is ok for me. I don't know whether the file connections.xml could be edited to change only some of the links.

Answer (score -1):

An excel file containing a MS SQL Query which returns no data (except for the headers) will also give you the same prompt when opening the file (“We found a problem with some content in [file]"). If you remove those queries, the prompt will stop.

Comment: Some examples or links, but this is no usable answer.